# How to retrieve youtube subtitle using youtube api

Tags: php

From the YouTube [caption request](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/captions) I got the `videoId` and `Id` parameter.

Now how to get authorization for one of the following scope to get youtube subtitle.

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner